# Groovy Date code producing unexpected output

Tags: date, grails, groovy

Why is below code producing output like this ?

```
String oldDate = "2013-12-05 01:34:54.270"
Date date = Date.parse( 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', oldDate )
Output : Sat Jan 05 01:34:54 EST 2013
```

When it should simply produce December 5 as the date in the output ? In fact in the original string whatever month I put in it produces the exact same output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your date format isn't correct. mm is for minutes where MM is for month. So it should be:

```
String oldDate = "2013-12-05 01:34:54.270"
Date date = Date.parse( 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', oldDate )
```

You can find out more from the Java API docs for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: It happens most of the times when someone works both in JavaScript and in Java/Groovy. @BigShow

Comment: I guess that hh should be HH, hh is for 0-12 hour (am or pm), HH is for 0-23. so it becomes yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: @bartoleo could be either, considering it wasn't clear from the question which was needed (since the question was centered around month and not hours) and that the question was using hh not HH to start with.

Comment: Yes bit I think that using hh instead of HH is another common mistake